# Can non-parametric tests, e.g. Mann-Whitney U, be used on non-normally distributed statistics off of bootstrap samples?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, bootstrap, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, finance

I have some return data from some different portfolios which I would like to compare using risk vs return ratios. The standard Sharpe ratio has a nice solution for calculating the significance of the difference between two Sharpe ratios and bootstraping and calculating the Sharpe ratios off the bootstrap samples comes out nicely normal anyway. However, the Sortino, for example, does not.

[Bootstraps of Sharpe vs Sortino Ratio](http://%3Chttps://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1057/palgrave.jam.2240123.pdf%3E): the ratios calculated off bootstraps are not normal.

For the ratios whose bootstrap values are not normal, can I use the Mann-Whitney U test to say that the Sortino ratio, for example, is significantly greater than zero or that the Sortino from one return series is significantly greater than another?